# Airflow DAG EMR EmrCreateJobFlowOperator Doesn't do anythong

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-emr, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to run an Airflow dag which Creates an EMR Cluster adds some steps, checks them and finally terminates the EMR Cluster that was created.
But when I run the Airflow Dag, it's continuously on running status and doesn't show any error or log.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here ??
Is there any missing parameter that I should add? 
Or It's the problem with the dag schedule ?

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_create_job_flow_operator import 
EmrCreateJobFlowOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_add_steps_operator import 
EmrAddStepsOperator
from airflow.contrib.sensors.emr_step_sensor import EmrStepSensor
from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_terminate_job_flow_operator import 
EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False
}


HIVE_CLOUDFRONT = [
{
    'Name': 'cloudfront',
    'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
    'HadoopJarStep': {
        'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
        'Args': [
            'hive-script',
             '--run-hive-script',
             '--args',
             '-f', 
             's3://BUCKET/xnder/scripts/Hive_CloudFront.q',
              '-d',
                            'INPUT=s3://BUCKET/',
             '-d',
                            'OUTPUT=s3://BUCKET/output5/'
        ]
    }
}
]

JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
'Name' : 'test1212',
'LogUri' : 's3://BUCKET/log.txt',
'ReleaseLabel' : 'emr-4.1.0',
'Instances' : {
  'InstanceGroups': [
        {
            'Name': 'Master nodes',
            'Market': 'ON_DEMAND',
            'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',
            'InstanceType': 'm1.large',
            'InstanceCount': 1,
        },
        {
            'Name': 'Slave nodes',
            'Market': 'ON_DEMAND',
            'InstanceRole': 'CORE',
            'InstanceType': 'm1.large',
            'InstanceCount': 1,
        }
    ],
    'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': True,
    'TerminationProtected': False
},
'Applications':[{ 
    'Name': 'Hadoop'
 }],
'JobFlowRole':'EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
'ServiceRole':'EMR_DefaultRole'
}

dag = DAG(
'emr_test_manual',
default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
#schedule_interval='0 3 * * *'
#schedule_interval=timedelta(seconds=10)
schedule_interval='@once'
)

cluster_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
task_id='create_job_flow_cluster',
job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
aws_conn_id='aws_default',
emr_conn_id='emr_default',
dag=dag
)

step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator(
task_id='add_steps',
job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
aws_conn_id='aws_default',
steps=HIVE_CLOUDFRONT,
dag=dag
)

step_checker = EmrStepSensor(
task_id='watch_step',
job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('add_steps', key='return_value')[0] }}",
aws_conn_id='aws_default',
dag=dag
)

cluster_remover = EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator(
task_id='remove_cluster',
job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
aws_conn_id='aws_default',
dag=dag
)

cluster_creator.set_downstream(step_adder)
step_adder.set_downstream(step_checker)
step_checker.set_downstream(cluster_remover)
```

Comment: We'll need more information to help you out. For once, start_date should be fixed, not dynamic. If you click on your first task instance, what's the state? On the Task Instance page, there is information about what might be blocking the task as well.

Comment: I resolve the problem.
The issue was with the server not code.

But now I'm getting a new error - "Specified job flow ID not valid"

Comment: I had a real hard time find some examples of a working EMR flow - this was great and got me up and running - thanks.

Comment: Was just playing around with the tool.
Glad to hear that it helped you !

You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Remove field 'Market': 'ON_DEMAND'